# URL is not defined in node.js

Tags: node.js, url

```
let url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
```

It will get an error like this:

> URL is not defined

Actually, in modern browsers, it works well. However, if you run it in the `node.js` environment, you will get an error like that.

I researched the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api), it says it's a global class:

> Browser-compatible URL class, implemented by following the WHATWG URL
>   Standard. Examples of parsed URLs may be found in the Standard itself.
>   The URL class is also available on the global object.

So, what's the problem?

Comment: Your Node version is old. There's URL global in Node 10. As for older versions, see the answer.

Comment: yes, you are right, my node.js version is 8

Comment: In the hopes of helping someone who comes here with the same issue, I just spent a frustrating hour finding out that this is the error message you will get if you try to run npm install from OUTSIDE OF a lando container.

Comment: This polyfill works for me on node.js version 8 and is ignored on node.js versions 10+: `if (!URL) var URL = require('url').URL;`

Answer (score 63):

Try to add this line:

```
var URL = require('url').URL;
```

The full example is here:

```
var URL = require('url').URL;
var myURL = new URL('http://www.example.com/foo?bar=1#main');

console.log(myURL.host);

// prints 'www.example.com'
```

All of those are from [this](https://www.nodebeginner.org/blog/post/nodejs-tutorial-whatwg-url-parser/) amazing tutorial.

Comment: What file?  Where are you supposed to add this line?

Comment: Nodejs official docs don't show the require. So that is good to know.

Answer (score 3):

`URL` is a global. Make sure you're using Node.js 10 or later. I had the same problem when using version `v8.11.2`.

You can use the following command to upgrade your node on Mac OS

```
brew upgrade node
```

or download from nodejs official website.

Comment: Is there any way to resolve this issue with v8?

Comment: Yes, add this line: `if (!URL) var URL = require('url').URL;`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just have to change your local version of node:

for example: `nvm use 12.18.3`

but earlier check what versions you already have `nvm list`